# Wrong colors appearing when getting the color from a data frame to geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I'm using this data frame where `Outcome` is the color that I want to assign to the `geom_segment`.

```
hori5 + 
    geom_segment(data = shots.Barcelona.df, 
     aes(x = X.ShotLocation,xend = X.EndLocation, y = Y.ShotLocation, 
         yend = Y.EndLocation,colour = Outcome),
     size=1,arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc")))
```

Using this code, I wanted to get black or red arrows but for some reason I get strange colors. This is what I get instead:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scale_colour_identity()`, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
dd <- data.frame(x=0:1,y=0:1,outcome=c("#000000","#FF0000"))
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y,colour=outcome)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_identity()
```